# Export Data-tier application error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bacpac, ssms-2014

I am trying to export a rather simple database using the Export Data-tier application and keep getting the following error:

*One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71564: The element Extended Property: [dbo].[DailyResult].[ScanTypeID].[MS_Description] is not supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file).*

I have removed the description for the indicated column, but continue to receive this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had a database reference in the offending object.  Once i removed that it exported without an issue. I changed;
    `[MyDatabase].[Work].[Job]`
to
    `[Work].[Job]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do as Amir978 suggested to remove the extended property, however, if you want to keep the extended property in your database and use Export, you can do this using the latest version of [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027).

The latest update to Microsoft Azure SQL Database (Azure V12) added support for Extended Properties, and the DacFx Export operation has been updated to allow extended properties.

Alternatively, if you are targeting more than just Azure, you can use the Extract functionality to produce a dacpac. A dacpac is not limited to just the set of features supported on Microsoft Azure SQL Databases.

I hope this helps

Lonny

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove Description manually. Instead try this script:

```
GO
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty 
    @name = N'MS_Description'

    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = dbo
    ,@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = 'tableName'
    ,@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = 'fieldName';
GO
```